# Finding the range of $f(x)=2\csc(2x)+\sec x+\csc x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Hi this is the question:

> Find the range of $$f(x)=2\csc(2x)+\sec x+\csc x$$

What I've tried:

I know that the range of $\csc(x)$ which is $R\setminus (-1,1) $, the range of $\sec(x)$ is $R\setminus (-1,1)$ too. And I've managed to simplify the expression to have in terms of $\sec x$ and $\csc x$ as such:
$$f(x)=\sec(x)\cdot \csc(x)+\sec(x)+\csc(x).$$
But then, what do I do when I have 3 terms and not just $\sec$ or $\csc$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\dfrac{1+\sin x+\cos x}{\sin x\cos x}$$

Clearly $f(x)$ is undefined for $2x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\dfrac{f(x)}2=\dfrac{1+\sin x+\cos x}{(\sin x+\cos x)^2-1}=\dfrac1{\sin x+\cos x-1} $$

Now use $-\sqrt2\le\sin x+\cos x\le\sqrt2$ to find

$$\implies-\sqrt2-1\le\sin x+\cos x-1\le\sqrt2-1$$

If $\sin x+\cos x-1\ge0, f(x)\ge2+2\sqrt2$

and if $\sin x+\cos x-1\le0,f(x)\le2-2\sqrt2$

Comment: What is that? Is there any other method

Comment: @Xetrez, Please pinpoint your confusion ?

Comment: How did you go from 1st to 2nd

Comment: @Xetrez, $$(\sin x+\cos x)^2-1=?$$

Comment: $1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)-1=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Comment: @Xetrez, I've replaced the value of $$\sin x\cos x$$

Comment: Is that an identity i didn't know of?

Comment: Whenever you are online back i'd like to ask more questions apart from that one.

Comment: @Xetrez, Please post questions, one at a time here for a better and a greater audience

Comment: Is sin x cos x =(sin x+cos x)²+1 an identity i didn't know? Once again

Comment: @Xetrez, Where have you found $$(\sin x+\cos x)^2+1$$

Comment: I meant -1 not +1

Comment: @Xetrez, I've compensated $2$ of $$2\sin x\cos x=(\sin x+\cos x)^2-1$$ in the left hand side.

Comment: I see, now what did you do from 2nd to 3rd

Comment: What did you do from 2nd to 3rd and how did you got that -sqrt(2)≤sin x +cos x≤2

Comment: Well, no. You have to take care that the function is undefined at $\pi$ and $3\pi/2$, which is possibly one of the main points of the exercise.

Comment: @egreg can you explain to me what they did on their steps? Your approach seems very far advanced

Comment: @egreg,The function is actually undefined  for $x=\dfrac{n\pi}2$

Comment: @Xetrez, Please find the updated answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Did I say it is defined?

Comment: @Xetrez The function does not assume the value $-1$, which this answer overlooks.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the secant function is $\sin x/\cos^2x$; the derivative of the cosecant function is $-\cos x/\sin^2x$, so you get
$$
f'(x)=-4\frac{\cos2x}{\sin^22x}+\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x}
=\frac{\sin^2x-\cos^2x+\sin^3x-\cos^3x}{\sin^2x\cos^2x}
$$
We can disregard the denominator and factor the numerator as
$$
(\sin x-\cos x)(\sin x+\cos x+\sin^2x+\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x)
=(\sin x-\cos x)(1+\sin x)(1+\cos x)
$$
Quite nicer! This is positive where $\sin x>\cos x$. Limiting ourselves to the interval $(0,2\pi)$, but also noting that the function is undefined at integer multiples of $\pi2$, we see that this happens for $\pi/4<x<5\pi/4$. Thus our function is

- decreasing over $(0,\pi/4)$
- increasing over $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$
- increasing over $(\pi/2,5\pi/4)$
- decreasing over $(5\pi/4,3\pi/2)$
- decreasing over $(3\pi/2,2\pi)$

Thus, taking into account the asymptotes, we see that the branch in $(0,\pi/2)$ has range $(f(\pi/4),\infty)=(2+2\sqrt{2},\infty)$.

The branch in $(\pi/2,2\pi)$ is a bit more complicated, because the function doesn't have asymptotes at $\pi$ and at $3\pi/2$. Indeed,
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi}f(x)=-1=\lim_{x\to3\pi/2}f(x)
$$
*If* we extend the function by continuity, the range over $(\pi/2,2\pi)$ would be $(-\infty,f(5\pi/4))=(-\infty,2-2\sqrt{2})$.

As the function is *not* defined at $\pi$ and $3\pi/2$, the range is
$$
(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,2-2\sqrt{2})\cup(2+2\sqrt{2},\infty)
$$

[image]

Comment: Why do we disregard the denominator?

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886615/are-the-sum-and-direct-sum-of-vector-subspaces-associative-and-commutative), please?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sin x+ \cos x-1} \implies y=\frac{1+t^2}{t-t^2} \implies (1+y)t^2-yt-1=0,$$
As $t=\tan(x/2)$ lies in $(-\infty, \infty)$, the range will be all values of $y$ when the above quadratic has real roots: $B^2 \ge 4AC$
$$\implies y^2-4y-4 \ge 0 \implies y\ge 2+\sqrt{2} ~or~ y\le2-\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we need

$\csc2x$ must be finite $\implies\sin2x\ne0\implies2x\ne n\pi\  \ \ \  (1)$ where $n$ is any integer

Now if $\sin x+\cos x+1=0,$

using double angle formula, $$\cos\dfrac x2\left(\sin\dfrac x2+\cos\dfrac x2\right)=0$$

$\cos\dfrac x2=0\iff x=(2r+1)\pi\  \ \ \  (2)$

and $\sin\dfrac x2+\cos\dfrac x2=0\implies x=2r\pi-\dfrac\pi2\  \ \ \  (3)$

Both $(2),(3)$ are been precluded by $(1)$

Let $\sin x+\cos x+1=k\implies k\ne0$

$\sin x\cos x=\dfrac{(\sin x+\cos x)^2-1}2=\dfrac{k^2-2k}2$

$f(x)=\dfrac{2k}{k(k-2)}=\dfrac2{k-2}$

As $k\ne0, f(x)\ne\dfrac2{0-2}\  \ \ \  (4)$

Now $-\sqrt2\le\sin x+\cos x\le\sqrt2\implies-\sqrt2-1\le k-2\le\sqrt2-1$

If $0< k\le\sqrt2-1, f(x)\ge\dfrac2{\sqrt2-1}=?$

If $0>k\ge-\sqrt2-1,  f(x)\le\dfrac2{-(\sqrt2+1)}=?$

But remember $(4)$

Comment: I don't understand this at all, where's the other solution you sent?

Comment: @Xetrez, I have deleted that, tried to put a cleaner solution! Where is your confusion

Comment: Why did you do so? It was so much simoler than THAT. I was only confused by some steps, what was wrong with the other one though? And this as far as i can comprehend, this looks way anove my level

Comment: @Xetrez, Undeleted temporarily. Please grasp basic trigonometric identities

Comment: alright thanks so much