# Are the sum and direct sum of vector subspaces associative and commutative?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> **Definition**
>
> If $S$ is a subset of a vector space $\mathscr{V}$ then the subspace $L(S)$ generated by $S$ is the smallest vector subspace of $\mathscr{V}$ containing $S$.
>
> **Proposition**
>
> The subspace $L(S)$ generated by $S$ is the set of all finite linear combination of vectors of $S$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are vector subspaces of $\mathscr{V}$ then their sum $W_1+W_2$ is the subspace $L(W_1\cup W_2)$ generated by $(W_1\cup W_2)$.
>
> **Proposition**
>
> If $W_1$ and $W_2$ are vector subspaces of $\mathscr{V}$ then
> $$
> W_1+W_2=\{w_1+w_2:w_1\in W_1,\,w_2\in W_2\}
> $$
>
> **Definition**
>
> The sum of two vector subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of $\mathscr{V}$ is direct if $W_1\cap W_2={0}$. In particular the finite sum of a collection $\mathcal{W}:=\{W_i: i\in\ I\}$ vector subspace is said direct if $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$ for each $i,j\in I$.

So with the previous formalism I’m asked to prove that the sum of subspaces is commutative and associative and the direct sum too. In the case of the simple sum I thought that this could trivially follow by the fact that
$$
W_1+W_2=\{w_1+w_2:w_1\in W_1,\,w_2\in W_2\}=\{w_2+w_1:w_2\in W_2,\,w_1\in W_1\}=W_2+W_1
$$
and
$$
W_1+(W_2+W_3)=\{w_1+(w_2+w_3):w_i\in W_i, i=1,2,3\}=\{(w_1+w_2)+w_3:w_i\in W_i, i=1,2,3\}=(W_1+W_2)+W_3
$$
but I am not sure about the correctedness of the arguement. Then I think that I cant implement the first argument to show that
$$
W_1\oplus W_2=W_2\oplus W_1
$$
but I still am not sure about this and finally if the second argument shows that the sum is associative I would have only prove that $(W_1\oplus W_2)\cap W_3=\{0\}$ but I don't be able to do this unfortunately. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The claim for sum also readily follows directly from the definition and commutativity and associativity of $\cup$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand exactely what you claim: indeed by the above definition we have $W_1+(W_2+W_3)=L(W_1\cup(W_2+W_3))=L(W_1\cup L(W_2+W_3))$ but unfortunately I don't see that immediately it is $L(W_1\cup L(W_2+W_3))=L(L(W_1\cup W_2)\cup W_3)=(W_1+W_2)+W_3$. So could you explain better, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $W_1+W_2=W_2+W_1$ is fairly obvious, because
$$
W_1+W_2=L(W_1\cup W_2)=L(W_2\cup W_1)=W_2+W_1
$$
by the very definition.

What about associativity? In this case you use the proposition: if $W_1,W_2,W_3$ are subspaces, $X=W_1+W_2$ and $Y=W_2+W_3$, you want to prove that
$$
X+W_3=W_1+Y
$$
Let $x\in X,w_3\in W_3$; then, by the proposition, $x=w_1+w_2$, with $w_1\in W_1$, $w_2\in W_2$; then
$$
x+w_3=(w_1+w_2)+w_3=w_1+(w_2+w_3)\in W_1+Y
$$
because $w_2+w_3\in Y$. Thus $X+W_3\subseteq W_1+Y$. The reverse inclusion follows similarly.

About direct sums there is a big misunderstanding. While the definition of “direct sum” in the case of two subspaces is correct, it is ***incorrect*** to say that the sum of more than two subspaces is direct when $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$ for $i\ne j$.

The condition is stricter, namely that
$$
W_i\cap\sum_{j\ne i}W_j=\{0\},\qquad i=1,2,\dots,n
$$
at least if one wants to stick with the common terminology and one of the most important properties of direct sums, namely that
$$
\dim(W_1\oplus W_2\oplus\dots\oplus W_n)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2+\dots+\dim W_n
$$
in case of finite dimensional spaces.

For instance, the enclosing vector space being $\mathbb{R}^3$, if $W_1$ is generated by $(1,0,0)$, $W_2$ by $(0,1,0)$ and $W_3$ by $(1,1,0)$, it is true that $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$, $W_1\cap W_3=\{0\}$, $W_2\cap W_3=\{0\}$, but
$$
\dim(W_1+W_2+W_3)=2\ne\dim W_1+\dim W_2+\dim W_3
$$

In any case, since a direct sum is a sum of subspaces to begin with, proving associativity (once the definition is fixed) and commutativity is not a problem, because it has already been done.

---

Let's tackle associativity of direct sum. Suppose $W_1,W_2,W_3$ are independent subspaces (meaning that their sum is direct). Then, ***by definition***,
$$
W_1\cap(W_2+W_3)=\{0\}=(W_1+W_2)\cap W_3
$$
Therefore also $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}=W_2\cap W_3$; hence $W_1+W_2=W_1\oplus W_2$ and $W_2+W_3=W_2\oplus W_3$. Hence
$$
W_1+(W_2+W_3)=W_1\oplus(W_2+W_3)=W_1\oplus(W_2\oplus W_3)
$$
$$
(W_1+W_2)+W_3=(W_1\oplus W_2)+W_3=(W_1\oplus W_2)\oplus W_3
$$
But these are equal by the previous argument.

Comment: Okay, I understand the first part of the answer but unfortuynately I have some problem with the second.

Comment: So you properly claim that the correct definition of direct sum must require that $i\neq j$ but unfortunately I don't understand why the above definition is equivalent to require that $W_i+\sum_{j\neq i}W_j=\{0\}$; moreover I don't absolutely understand how adapt the above arguments to the direct sum to prove associativity: indeed we know that $W_1\bigoplus(W_2\bigoplus W_3)=W_1+(W_2+W_3)=(W_1+W_2)+W_3=(W_1\bigoplus W_2)+W_3$ but unfortunately we don't know if $(W_1+W_2)\cap W_3=\{0\}$ so how to prove it?

Comment: Could you explain these things to me, please? Excuse me too much: in particular forgive my confusion.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I claim that the definition of direct sum of subspaces ***not only*** requires $i\ne j$ (which is fairly obvious), but a ***much stricter*** condition.

Comment: Okay, but the much stricter condiction it seems that it implies that $W_i=\{0\}$ for each $i=1,...,k$ so that why this is false? Then what can you say about proof of direct sum?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Why should it imply $W_i=\{0\}$? Your condition does, because you don't state $i\ne j$. The stricter condition is $$W_i\cap \sum_{j\ne i}W_j=\{0\}$$ that is, each subspace must intersect trivially the sum of *all* the others.

Comment: Okay, now I understood: the problem was that you wrote $W_i+\sum_{j\ne i}W_j=\{0\}$ instead of $W_i\cap \sum_{j\ne i}W_j=\{0\}$, that's all.

Comment: So to summarise. We say that the sum of $W_1,...,W_k$ is direct if $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$ for each $i\neq j$ **AND** if $W_i\cap \sum_{j\ne i}W_j=\{0\}$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro The second condition is obviously stronger than the first one, so the first one is not needed. About your previous comment, I don't understand: you just repeat twice the same expression I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Oh, yeah! Indeed if $W_j\subseteq L\big(\bigcup_{h\neq i} W_h\big)=\sum_{h\neq i} W_h$ so that if $W_i\cap\sum_{h\neq j}=\{0\}$ then necessarily $W_i\cap W_j=\{0\}$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Yes. But I find this approach very distasteful. Not your fault, of course.

Comment: Oh, don't worry the mistake has been done by my text book that is *Algebra Lineare e Geometria* by Francesco Bottacin. Anyway thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I added the proof for the direct sum, adding to my distaste. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I read: it is clear. Anyway I meanwhile reflected about my doubts and I concluded that my confusion was this: since we first define $U_1\bigoplus....\bigoplus U_k$ I thought that before to prove associativity we  have to prove that $U_1\bigoplus U_2\bigoplus U_3=U_1\bigoplus (U_2\bigoplus U_3)$ but now it seems to me that using associativity then we can define $U_1\bigoplus....\bigoplus U_k$ however I continue to be hesitant which strategy adopt, that's all. So what do you think about?